# Expo on MacOS can open my app on my Android device over USB cable via XDE but not commandline

Tags: android, macos, command-line, usb, expo

I'm new to Android and Macs and React Native.

I'm using a MacBook Air with Sierra connected by USB cable to a new Android phone.

Using Expo's IDE I can run and test my app on my Android device but when I try to do the same via the Terminal I always get network errors.

Why does the commandline version want to use internet when XDE is happy to work with the USB cable and how can I change it?

Googling the issue has been elusive so far.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download adb from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/index.html)
2. cd into the directory you downloaded, and then into the tools directory.
3. Plug in your phone
4. Run './adb devices', It should spit out an id and say 'device', if it says 'unkown', try restarting the phone, or otherwise get it to the device.
5. './adb install app_path.apk', and it should install.

Good luck.

Comment: There's no tools directory in the current version but I ran it and got the id OK. But step 5 failed with `adb: error: cannot stat 'app_path.apk': No such file or directory`

Comment: where is your 'app_path.apk'? located?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm starting from scratch on several techs at once \-:

Comment: Where is your projects file? not .apk but the whole project??

Comment: Is this projects file part of the app I'm working on or part of the setup of Expo/Android SDK/React Native? Still looking ...

Comment: The app I'm working on is in a dir off my homedir but I can't find this .apk in there yet.

Comment: go to build-->generate .apk--> fill form-->release unsigned .apk and while releasing show the path to homedir

Comment: I can't niether find "build" in the XDE menus or a command in the path in the Terminal ...

Answer (score 0):

**To view a project you must have an exp server running for that project. Run `exp start` to start running the server. Once it is ready it'll output a url for your project.**

```
$ exp start
```

...
**[exp] Your URL is some thing like this.**

```
exp://3h-xu5.jesse.expo-example.exp.direct
```

The server will continue running until you close it.

**To view this on your phone, do the following:**

Go get the Expo Client app on your Android or iOS device. It's available on the Google Play Store and on the iOS App Store.

Run `exp send` to send a link via `email or text`. You can also use the --send-to option when running exp start.

> Check your e-mail or texts and tap the link. The Expo app should open
>   and you should be able to view your experience there!